# Vimtex variables are said to be undefined (so I can't change them)

Tags: vim

I'm using the [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) plugin with [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) plugin manager to edit LaTex files.  I'm trying to disable the Callback feature in my vimrc (so I stop getting warnings about it whenever I open a .tex file), so I `let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk.callback = 0`, but I get an error saying `g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk` is an undefined variable.

Attempting `:echo g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk` gives the same error message.

The **only** variable I can seem to change or even view is `g:vimtex_enabled`, so if I want to `let g:vimtex_enabled = 0`, I can do that and disable vimtex altogether.

Any ideas why and what I can do to fix this?  Vimtex otherwise works flawlessly despite this.

I'm running VIM 7.4 on Linux Mint 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim doesn't let you initialize a dictionary variable like that. There's no default value for `g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk`, so you first have to initialize it as a dictionary:

```
let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {}
let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk.callback = 0
```

Or just initialize and assign at once:

```
let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {'callback': 0}
```

Either way, once it's initialized, you can use the `.` accessor shortcut.

The reason you're only seeing `g:vimtex_enabled` is because vimtex autoloads when you access a `.tex` file. Load one up, and you'll see a lot more variables. You still won't see `g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk`, though, because it has no value unless you set one.

I suspect you are assigning `g:vimtex_enabled` in your vimrc, and that's why you see that one even without loading a LaTeX file.

Comment: Thank you.  The possibility that the dictionary wasn't already initialized hadn't crossed my mind.  That is definitely something I will remember for the future.